# get length of nested array in assembly

Tags: assembly

How to get length of foo[1] in example below in assembly?

```
uint[][] foo; // foo.length = 2, foo[1].length = 3

function getLength() returns (uint len) {
    assembly {
        len := sload(foo) // returns 2
        len := sload(........) // how to return foo[1] ?
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[This guide](https://programtheblockchain.com/posts/2018/03/09/understanding-ethereum-smart-contract-storage/) explained it fairly well. The storage pointers for nested arrays are organized as nested hash functions. At level one, `keccak256(foo_slot)`, are the lengths for all first order arrays, `foo[0]`, `foo[1]`, `foo[2]`, etc. The length of each individual subarray is, correspondingly, `keccak256(foo_slot)`, `keccak256(foo_slot) + 1`, `keccak256(foo_slot) + 2`, etc.

In the example asked about, the length of `foo[1]` is found with:

```
len := sload(add(keccak256(foo_slot, 32), 1)
```